# How to create wave splashes onto another object, such as a shiphull?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, physics

Effect would replicate the following and can be a mesh or effect. [image]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)